# Get a Objective-C method to return several NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, string, pointers

I need to use a method that returns several strings, different ones, according to a value.
My code looks like:

```
- (void) returnStringsAccordingToSet:(NSString *)string1: (NSString *)string2: (NSInteger)setNo {
    switch (setNo){
        case 1:
            if (generalStringSettings){
                string1 = @"The first string";
                string2 = @"The second string";
            } else {
                string1 = @"The first other string";
                string2 = @"The second other string";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
             ...
             break;
        case 3:
             ...
             break;
    }
}
```

I call that method with:

`NSString *firstString = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSString *secondString = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSUInteger set  = 1;

[self getStringsAccordingToSet: firstString: secondString: set];`

I can't get it to work! All I get is empty strings. I've got a feeling that the call for the strings is somewhat wrong. Please help.

Comment: Generally this would be done by returning an NSArray or NSDictionary containing the strings.  However, you can also pass indirect references, where you reference the pointer to the array (with `&`) rather than value in the pointer.

Comment: It's possible to change the parameters you've been passed using another level of indirection but in a language that returns objects, it's not really a good idea.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for that- I will try alter nt code accordingly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by filling a NSArray, but just to show how C works I'll show the error that you made.
string1 and string2 are just pointers, so you can pass either mutable or immutable strings as arguments.But the original pointer never gets modified, for example:

```
NSString* string1=@"Hello";  // Let's suppose string1 is on the 0x8000 address
                             // And points to the 0x9000 address
NSString* string2=@"How are you?";  // string2: 0x1000 , pointing to 0x2000
[self returnStringsAccordingToSet: string1: string1 string2: string2];
```

Then when you call a method a copy is made for every pointer that you pass to the method:

```
- (void) returnStringsAccordingToSet:(NSString *)string1: (NSString *)string2: (NSInteger)setNo {
// string1 and string2 both point on the same address, but they are other pointers
// for example string1 is on 0x7000 and string2 on 0x7400, pointing to 0x9000
// and 0x2000
    switch (setNo){
        case 1:
            if (generalStringSettings){
                string1 = @"The first string";  // You just create another instance
                string2 = @"The second string"; // of the string, but the original
                // pointers aren't affected
            } else {
                string1 = @"The first other string";
                string2 = @"The second other string";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
             ...
             break;
        case 3:
             ...
             break;
    }
}
```

The solutions:

1. Pass a NSMutableString as argument and instead of assigning them, just modify the contents;
2. Pass a pointer to pointer;
3. Return a NSArray containing the new strings.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. An answer worthy a place in a book.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mae it work because when you do

```
string1 = @"The first string";
```

you just override the local parameter and update its reference but nothing outside the callee is modified. So the value is changed just inside the scope of the function.

You should change the signature of the method to

```
- (NSArray*) returnStringsAccordingToSet:(NSString *)string1: (NSString *)string2: (NSInteger)setNo {
```

so that it returns a NSArray instead that nothing and then inside the function

```
case1:
  return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"The first string",@"The second string",nil];
```

so you return the array and store it from the caller, then you can access the returned values.

```
NSArray *v = [returnStringAccordingTo: ..];
[v objectAtIndex:0]
```

Technically, since ObjectiveC is a superset of C, I guess it is possible to pass a pointer to a pointer to `NSString` by reference through (but this is discouraged in ObjC):

```
NSString *string = nil;
[self callMethod:&string];

-(void)callMethod:(NSString**)refToString {
  *refToString = @"foobar";
```

Comment: It works like a charm..the code looks much more neat when I started to use NSArray:s instead!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Update note:** I personally don't use the method as a first thing to do. I use arrays if that's possible. Not sure if it's OK to use this with ARC. Some Apple methods use this approach to return error value, so it's good to be aware of it.

When method is called, those arguments you pass to function are copied (of course they are not getting the copy message, pointer is copied as far as you pass pointer), and those copies are used inside the function (or more technically initiated with the argument value). So if you change the copy (i.e. try to replace object on pointer, mutable objects are OK to modify) this will not reflect on the value. You may solve this using pointers (i.e. pass pointer to pointer).

So:

```
NSString* string = @"one string";
NSLog(string); // one string

// [self method:string]
- (void) method: (NSString*) string {
    // Local copy created:
    // NSString* string = copy of string (second pointer created, object not copied in memory)
    string = @"other string";
    NSLog(string); // other string
}

NSLog(string); // one string
```

You may do this like that:

```
- (void) method: (NSString**)str {
    *str = @"Some string";
}
```

and then:

```
// string = "old vlalue"
NSString* string = @"old value";

// string = "Some string"
[self method:&string];
```

Comment: ... but this method is NOT liked by ARC. it errors back that I shouldn't use '&'.

Comment: Your description isn't correct. A copy of the string is NOT made. A copy of the pointer is made, not a copy of the object. If you pass in a mutable object as a parameter, then changes made to the mutable object in the method are also reflected in the object where the method was called.

Comment: @rmaddy I just wanted to simplify that a bit, see that (initiated with the value part), I really beleive it's easy to understand that the way I described, anyway, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @rmaddy and note, that I didn't mention that object is copied, I wrote that the argument is copied, and argument is the pointer. Just not as clear as It could be.

Comment: @MANIAK_dobrii Your original answer clearly showed (as a comment in the code) that the object was copied. Anyway, your update is better.